# How to get environmental variables of a very short process?

Tags: process, environment-variables, proc

I have a very short process for which i want to check the environmental variables for debugging purposes. The process is instant from a human perspective. The example illustrates it better.

**Example**

```
user:~$ ps aux | grep grep
user   2349  0.0  0.0   4384   840 pts/1    S+   14:47   0:00 grep --color=auto grep
```

The pid of the process was 2349. If I check the environmental variables (or other info):

```
#Pretty print of environmental variables#
user:~$ xargs --null --max-args=1 echo < /proc/2349/environ
bash: /proc/2349/environ: No such file or directory
```

The info has vanished with the process.

What to do before running the process to be able to list the variables once the precess is finished?

Comment: If you use ams's idea with a shell wrapper, you can also get the pid (your other question) -- since the real process is launched via `exec`, its pid will be the same (`$$`) as the shell it *replaced.*

Comment: Related: [How to get the id of a very short child process if the parent is known?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83088/how-to-get-the-id-of-a-very-short-child-process-if-the-parent-is-known) (most solutions to one also solve the other)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

if you have `strace`

```
strace -v -e execve cmd
```

If the values of the variables are too long you can increase the string size with `-s`

```
strace -v -s 10000 -e execve cmd
```

Comment: `-v` is what I was missing. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

I would move the binary to one side and create a wrapper that dumps the environment to a file and then calls the original.

E.g.

```
mv ${cmd} ${cmd}.moved
```

Then create a new file `${cmd}`:

```
#!/bin/sh
env > /tmp/cmd-env.log
exec ${cmd}.moved "$@"
```

And, don't forget the permissions:

```
chmod a+rx ${cmd}
```

Then, wait for it to run again, and read the environment from `/tmp/cmd-env.log`.

Finally, put the original program back where it came from:

```
mv ${cmd}.moved ${cmd}
```

Of course, it may be possible to avoid moving the binary by putting the wrapper in another `bin` directory earlier in `$PATH`.